# How to get partial data from an existing column of an sql table?

Tags: sql, substring

table name `Test`

column name - `url`

data (10 rows):

```
1 http://example.com/mollybsims/

2 http://example.com/jillianmharris/

3 ...

4 ...

5 ...
```

I want only the strings 'mollybsims', 'jillianmharris' and so forth in a new column. I am using sub string function in update query. But how exactly it's done is my real question.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: @ashirwad markar - as already asked above, please supply which "flavor" of SQL you're using.  We need to determine if regular expressions are supported and, if so, to what extent.

Comment: MS SQL 2008 is that what you are asking?

Comment: MS SQL SERVER 2008..i hope this information is good enough...i need a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

*Select REPLACE(REPLACE(url,'http://example.com/',''),'/','')*

Hope this is what you required.

Comment: It should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: will try your suggestion...but will this create a new column? for the required string like 'mollybsims'?

Comment: Where you want to create new column? You can add "as YourDesiredColumnName" at the end of above query if you want to create alias name for this string.